# wxMaxima compare logical expressions

Tags: maxima

I´m new to wxMaxima and can not figure out how to compare two logical expressions..
For example:

```
test1:(A and B) or C;
test2:(A or C) and (B or C);

is(test1=test2);
```

should be

```
true
```

but the result is

```
false
```

What i´m doing wrong here?!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [a logic algebra package](http://beshenov.ru/maxima/logic/).

```
load("logic.mac");
test1:(A and B) or C;
test2:(A or C) and (B or C);
logic_equiv(test2, test1 );
(%o20)                               true
```

Comment: The link that you posted is broken now. Is there any replacement for it?

Comment: @Anderson Green It is a part of maxima. Install a recent version or
grub the package from maxima source code
http://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/code/ci/master/tree/share/logic